# A issue occurred evaluating project ':ActionBarSherlock'

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

```
When i try to sync my project i got Below Error ,what was the wrong in my gradle file
```

Error:
           A problem occurred evaluating project ':ActionBarSherlock'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
>   Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.

Build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

   sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug  /AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
 }
 }
```

Comment: I guess ActionBarSherlock is deprecated. Use the new AppCompatActivity.

Comment: today only i got this issue @RohanSood